# pywinauto wait for window to appear not working

Tags: wait, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto to automate a DeskTop apllication and I need to wait an application be 'Ready" in order to go ahead with the other commands.

Can someone identify what I'm doing wrong in this code :

```
import time
import pyautogui
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

#app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
app = Application(backend='uia').start(r"\\10.2.0.11\sistema\XXXXXXXXXX\PRINCIPAL\Principal.exe")
time.sleep(0.5)
app.TeladeEntrada.Edit.type_keys("17345555{ENTER}", pause=0)

time.sleep(2)
BotaoTransportes = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("C:\\Users\\foldername\\Fontes PY\\BotaoTransportes.PNG", grayscale=False)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.moveTo(BotaoTransportes[0],BotaoTransportes[1])
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click()

app.window(title='(SISLOG) Sistema de informações logísticas (Rodoviário)').wait('ready', timeout=10)
time.sleep(3)
```

The command App.windows wait does not work, and always return timeout, but I can see that the application is ready.

This is the print screen of the application

[image]

So I'm sure that the application title is correct.

I will appreciate any coments about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the new window has the same Process ID in `Inspect.exe` than previous window. If it's not the same, you have to do `app.connect(title="(SISLOG) Sistema de informações logísticas (Rodoviário)", timeout=10)`.